# Pandas dataframe groupby on date field

Tags: python, pandas

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(zip(np.random.rand(5).tolist(), [1]*5, [dt.date.today()]*5), columns=list('abc'))
>>> df
    a   b   c
0   0.896739    1   2017-09-24
1   0.473168    1   2017-09-24
2   0.100591    1   2017-09-24
3   0.870899    1   2017-09-24
4   0.716934    1   2017-09-24

>>> print df.groupby('c').a.apply(lambda x: x.max()).index
Index([2017-09-24], dtype='object', name=u'c')

>>> df.groupby(['b', 'c']).a.apply(lambda x: x.max()).index
MultiIndex(levels=[[1], [2017-09-24 00:00:00]], labels=[[0], [0]],
       names=[u'b', u'c'])

>>> print df.groupby(['b', 'c']).a.max().index
MultiIndex(levels=[[1], [2017-09-24]], labels=[[0], [0]],
       names=[u'b', u'c'])
```

Why is the date field converted to datetime (only) in second case when grouping?

I am using pandas 0.19.2

Comment: Same problem in `0.20.3` - it looks like bug. `print (df.groupby(['b', 'c']).a.apply(lambda x: x.max()).index.get_level_values(1))`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, only in the second case, the date field is converted to a **Timestamp**. In case 1 and 3, the date fields are Datetime:

```py
print df.groupby('c').a.apply(lambda x: x.max()).index.tolist()
print df.groupby(['b', 'c']).a.apply(lambda x: x.max()).index.tolist()
```

But a very interesting observation. Index and Multiindex as well as Series.max() and Series.apply() do not seem to be implemented consistently when it comes to handling datetime.date objects.

**Solution**: If you convert `dt.date.today()` to a pandas.Timestamp or numpy.datetime64 from the beginning, the date fields are all consistently Timestamps:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(np.random.rand(5).tolist(), [1]*5, [np.datetime64(dt.date.today())]*5)), columns=list('abc'))
print(df.groupby('c').a.apply(lambda x: x.max()).index.tolist())
print(df.groupby('c').a.max().index.tolist())
print(df.groupby(['b', 'c']).a.apply(lambda x: x.max()).index.tolist())
print(df.groupby(['b', 'c']).a.max().index.tolist())
```